# Delegate to an instance method cannot have null Intermittent on runtime

Tags: c#, delegates

I got this error and cannot understand this error. 
I use win form and .net 3.5.
The problem is, this can be compiled and intermittent. Just shown today, so i guess this occur very rare (maybe once after 5000 run). I want to know what makes this error thrown, and any possible workaround.
Here is the example of how I implemented the code.

My application is multithread, and this method is singleton.

---

```
Exception type: System.ArgumentException
Exception message: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.
Exception stack trace: 
   at System.MulticastDelegate.ThrowNullThisInDelegateToInstance()
   at System.MulticastDelegate.CtorClosed(Object target, IntPtr methodPtr)
```

---

```
  class Caller
  {
    private ClassA theA;
    public Caller()
    {
      theA = new ClassA();
    }

    public void button_click()
    {
      theA.Execute(false);
    }
    public void button2_click()
    {
      theA.Execute( true );
    }
  }

  interface IClassA
  {
    void ActionMinus();
  }
  class ClassA
  {
    public int VariableA = 0;
    public void Execute( bool wait )
    {
      ClassB instanceB = new ClassB( this );
      Thread thread = new Thread( instanceB.Action ) // error in here
      { 
        Name = "Executor",
        Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
      };

      thread.Start();
      if( wait )
        thread.Join();
    }
    public void ActionMinus()
    {
      //someAction1
      VariableA -= 2;
      //someAction2
    }
  }

  class ClassB
  {
    private readonly ClassA instanceA;
    public ClassB( ClassA instance )
    {
      instanceA = instance;
    }
    public void Action()
    {
      //some other action3
      instanceA.VariableA += 5;
      //some other action4
      instanceA.ActionMinus();
      //some other action5
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem (even intermittently). Your post so far implies that `instanceB` is `null` when the delegate for the thread is created, but there's nothing here that would do that. Lacking a complete code example, it will be very difficult to guess what the actual problem is.

Comment: First of all you do have lots of compilation error like missing return type ahead of `ActionMinus` missing class keyword ahead of `ClassB` and many more... resolve it and you would get fine working code.

Comment: Edit the code @PeterDuniho, I believe instanceB is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it works to me.

What is the context of your program?

I wrote a simple empty shell containing your code, but the program will end before the thread gets kicked off.

I had to add a Console.ReadKey() method.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the whole code I used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace DelegateToInstance {

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var obj = new Caller();
      obj.button_click();
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  class Caller
  {
    private ClassA theA;
    public Caller()
    {
      theA = new ClassA();
    }

    public void button_click()
    {
      theA.Execute(false);
    }
    public void button2_click()
    {
      theA.Execute( true );
    }
  }

  interface IClassA
  {
    void ActionMinus();
  }

  class ClassA
  {
    public int VariableA = 0;
    public void Execute( bool wait )
    {
      ClassB instanceB = new ClassB(this);
      Thread thread = new Thread( instanceB.Action ) // error in here
      { 
        Name = "Executor",
        Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
      };

      thread.Start();
      if( wait )
        thread.Join();
    }
    public void ActionMinus()
    {
      //someAction1
      VariableA -= 2;
      //someAction2
    }
  }

  class ClassB
  {
    private readonly ClassA instanceA;
    public ClassB( ClassA instance )
    {
      instanceA = instance;
    }
    public void Action()
    {
      //some other action3
      instanceA.VariableA += 5;
      //some other action4
      instanceA.ActionMinus();
      //some other action5
    }
  }

}
```

I hate downvoters, so I gave you an upvote.

Comment: Thanks jp. I can't see your screen shoot. And yes, the code usually works, but yesterday I got that intermittent error. This is the first time I see it, and I can't reproduce it. I can't understand why it throw that error.

Comment: The ClassB is for sending command to hardware. The program end first because we are only use simple command. If using win form, after a button click, it will send command to hardware and the UI still accessible.

Comment: If the program ends first, that would cause your null reference exception. You may need to use a [ManualResetEvent control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent) to ensure your object remains alive until you are finished with it.

Comment: It appears I got a downvote for upvoting yours. Upvote me so we are at a net 0.

Comment: If the error shown when program ends, i think it's okay. But the program is not end at that time.

Comment: Here is a similar question, asked in 2010: [Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3752824/153923) Perhaps it can provide insight to your problem.

Comment: You are obviously not alone. Here is another link, this one on MSDN: [Why do I need a null test before I invoke a delegate?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/19/why-do-i-need-a-null-test-before-i-invoke-a-delegate.aspx)